# How to get the color and background color in docusaurus programatically?

Tags: docusaurus

I'm using a `Chart` component from [`react-google-charts`](https://www.react-google-charts.com/) and I'd like to put it in a mdx page and adjust its colors to the page colors. What's the best way to get the `color` and `backgroundColor`?

```
Here is my chart:

<Chart
    chartType="ColumnChart"
    loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
    data={[
        ['A', '1'],
        ['B', '2'],
        ['C', '3'],
    ]}
    options={{
        title: 'Graphic view',
        chartArea: { left: 0 },
        backgroundColor: {*** Here I want to use the page's default background color ***},
        colors: [{*** Here I want to use the page's default text color ***}],
    }}
    legendToggle
/>
```